# Testing collections with FSUnit.Xunit

Tags: f#, xunit

I'm trying to test equality of two collections in F# using FSUnit (specifically its Xunit branch) but failing horribly so far.

I have a function that returns an array of certain structs and would like to test whether the returned array is correct. The code I'm testing is in C# so it so the function can't return native F# lists.

The most promising approach I've tried is following:

```
[<Fact>]
let SimpleTest() = 
    let parser = new ExpressionParser()
    parser.ParseExpression "2" |> should equal [new ParsedItem("2", ParsedItemType.Value)]
```

...but it results in the the test failing because of:

```
"Message> FSUnit.Xunit+MatchException: Exception of type 'FsUnit.Xunit+MatchException' was thrown. 

Expected value: Equals [(2)]
Actual: was [2]
```

I can see that it's because the type of native F# list doesn't match a native array but have honestly no idea (nor have I found anything in documentation) how to do it differently (other then creating native array beforehand and populating it one by one...).

I've also tried some other approaches but they usually wouldn't even compile.

---

PS: I'm completely new to both F# and Xunit so I might be missing something absolutely obvious.

**EDIT:** A workaround that actually works better was suggested in comments (comparing string representations instead of the objects themselves) and while I will use that in my actual code I'd still appreciate a true solution to my problem above.

Comment: Not that I have an answer but might help others looking at this. Is using XUnit a requirement or can you change to use NUnit?

Comment: I can change to NUnit without any problems but would prefer a FSUnit native solution.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot convert the structures to a printable form and compare the printable forms or write a custom compare function and call that. One project that I worked on used FSUnit with NUnit and we did lots of comparisons of AST in a printed form. See [Tests](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning.Tests/equal.fs)

Comment: Does the type `ParsedItem` have comparison defined?

Comment: 1) You're right, what I meant by FSUnit native solution was that I didn't want an answer such as "switch to NUnit and use Collection.Equal directly". 2) Comparing printable form sure sounds interesting, didn't thought of that (and or would even save me the trouble of creating result arrays). 3) well, it being a struct means it has a default EqualityComparer, but it doesn't have a comparer as it doesn't make sense to order them.

Comment: The nice thing about the comparing the printable forms is that you can just run the function with the test data and print out the result, then cut and paste that as the expected answer, of course manually checking that it is a valid answer, and then rinse and repeat. The AST or what ever is printed must be in a [Canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form). Also anyone coming latter can see the values and not try and guess as to what the expected result is really.

Comment: That sounds great and will probably do it that way... would still appreciate the answer though. If only for educational purposes.

Comment: No, I can (or at least I hope so :) ) follow your advice by myself. I meant that I'd appreciate an answer to my original problem -> how to resolve collection equality assertion. Your advice is a good one but it's more of a workaround (though in this case a superior one) than a true solution.

Comment: @guycoder I know about that but the official mobile app doesn't have support for that so you have to guess people's user tags... Anyway, thanks a lot and have a nice evening or whatever time it is in your time zone :)

Comment: I didn't know that; never used the mobile app. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer and it's simpler than I thought it'd be. First off the assentation works well the problem was in syntax and me not bothering to read the documentation on how to create an array in F# and just guessing it.

There were two things wrong. First `[new ParsedItem("2", ParsedItemType.Value)]` doesn't create an array it creates a list. That in itself wouldn't be a problem for FSUnit's `should equal` but it's enough to make simple structural equality test using `=` fail.

The second thing that was wrong was that I didn't really compare with `[new ParsedItem("2", ParsedItemType.Value)]` I compared with  `[new ParsedItem("2", ParsedItemType.Value), new ParsedItem("+", ParsedItemType.Operator), new ParsedItem("3", ParsedItemType.Value)]` and that actually creates a list containing *one touple*. And that - unsurprisingly - didn't assert well :).

Simply reading the documentation and learning that an array is supposed to be created `[|new ParsedItem("2", ParsedItemType.Value); new ParsedItem("+", ParsedItemType.Operator); new ParsedItem("3", ParsedItemType.Value)|]` fixed the issue.

---

Anyway, thanks for the comments and the other answer. Though they didn't answer my question they increased my knowledge about F# and gave me a new idea how to test :).

Answer (score 3):

Although you can't easily return F# lists from your C# code, one option is to return arrays. These have structural equality, so you can simply compare them to determine if they are equal to each other:

```
open System.Linq

let csharpArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray()
let fsharpArray = [| 0..9 |]
```

These two arrays are equal:

```
> csharpArray = fsharpArray;;
val it : bool = true
```

If you don't want to return arrays, you can also return `IEnumerable<T>`, and convert to either lists or arrays in F#:

```
> let csharpEnumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);;    
val csharpEnumerable : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>

> csharpEnumerable |> Seq.toList = [0..9];;
val it : bool = true
```

---

For a more comprehensive to introduction to unit testing with F#, you may want to [view my Pluralsight course on the topic](http://bit.ly/unittestingwithfsharp).

Comment: How did the test fail, then? I mean the values were the same and ParseExpression returns an array? Thinking about it, it looks as if "the array I'm compering the result to isn't an array but an one-element-long array containing a tupple (just guessing from based on the test message )... Will look into that.

Comment: @Petrroll In my answer, the *values* in the arrays are `int` values, which have structural equality. So do all other value types, record types and discriminated unions in F#, but most .NET objects don't. By default, .NET objects have reference equality. [My Pluralsight course](http://bit.ly/unittestingwithfsharp) has more details.

Comment: Yep I know but the array is an array of structs and structs have a default EqualityComparer that then (though if the struct contains a ref field trough slow reflection) compares each member field using their equality comparers. And the member fields on my stucts are either value types or strings (which again has an overriden equality comparer)... So that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @Petrroll It'd help if you posted your code, but have you tried to compare the two arrays using F#'s `=` operator? That would tell you whether the problem is with the framework comparison, or with FsUnit.